# Using PHP and Drupal username

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to do something where PHP reads the username logged in (I'm using Drupal) and then read a simple csv file in a directory I create for that user.

I verified that, yes, php is reading and storing my username to the variable I set up ($uname). I did a test where I echoed $uname and it works, and indeed shows my username on the site. However, when I concatencate the path, I get an error saying that the directory doesn't exist and the error shows everything except the username.

Here's what I have:

```
<?php

global $user;
$uname= $user->name;
$fdir = "./users/";
$fname="test.csv";
$slash = "/";

$fpath = $fdir.$uname.$slash.$fname;


$file_handle = fopen($fpath, "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1]. $line_of_text[2] . "<BR>";

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

UPDATED:

I am able to read a csv with a username *if* the file is in the same directory as the PHP script. However, I can't get it to use the username to go the subdirectory which is named after the user. How do I get this to happen?

Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [rubber ducky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: LOL. I'm still pretty new to PHP. The directory I'm trying to access is /users/username and this is my first attempt at doing something with stringing together a directory path to point to a file.

Comment: You need this to be relative to the server root or the php file's directory ?

Comment: @Ayesh K, I think it has to be relative to the php file directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm...well, you're going to find this odd but this code works only if you put it into an article or page you create within Drupal and set it to contain PHP code. If you run it outside of Drupal (i.e., as a standalone PHP script), doesn't work and it won't pick up the username logged into the Drupal site. Meh.

Comment: You can try bootstrapping Drupal to external pages.